# List view with rawquery Could not execute method

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor, adapter

I have a little issue that I don't know how to address.
I have a Cursor that gets data from my data base it looks like this:

```
public Cursor getAllData(){
    int id;
    SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String dateTime = Helper.getCurrentDate();
    String date = dateTime.substring(0, 10);
    String date_to_look = date.substring(0, 10);
    String sql = "SELECT h.product_id, h.qty, h.date_time, p.product " +
            " FROM product_history h " +
            " LEFT JOIN products p ON (p.rowid = h.product_id) ";
    Cursor res = DB.rawQuery(sql, null);
    return res;
}
```

Then on my activity I'm using the following method:

```
public void populateListView() {
      Cursor cursordata = myDb.getAllData();
      String productname = cursordata.getString(cursordata.getColumnIndex("product"));
       String [] products = {productname};    
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, products);
       ListView listviewman = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewman);
       listviewman.setAdapter(adapter);

       }
```

Execute it with onclick:

```
public void shine(View v){
    Button shine = (Button)findViewById(R.id.shine);
    populateListView();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: 
Shows last row from the table only.

```
public void populateListView() {
       Cursor cursordata = myDb.getAllData();

       if (cursordata.moveToFirst()) {
           do {
               String productname = cursordata.getString((cursordata.getColumnIndex("product")));
               String [] products = {productname};
               ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, products);
               ListView listviewman = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewman);
               listviewman.setAdapter(adapter);

           } while (cursordata.moveToNext());
       }
```

Sahil here is the updated version of your suggestion which i use, it's not working:

```
 public void populateListView() {
    Cursor cursordata = myDb.getAllData();
    List<String> li_records=new ArrayList<String>;

    if (cursordata.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String productname = cursordata.getString((cursordata.getColumnIndex("product")));
            String[] products = {productname};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, products);
            ListView listviewman = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewman);
            listviewman.setAdapter(adapter);
            li_records.add(productname);

        } while (cursordata.moveToNext());
    }
    String[] products=li_records.toArray();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this it will work fine:**

```
public void populateListView() {
       Cursor cursordata = myDb.getAllData();
            ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<>();

       if (cursordata.moveToFirst()) {
           do {
               String productname = cursordata.getString((cursordata.getColumnIndex("product")));
               products.add(productname);

           } while (cursordata.moveToNext());
       }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, products);
               ListView listviewman = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewman);
               listviewman.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

Comment: Error:(75, 17) error: variable products might not have been initialized

Comment: This one actually worked, had to replace ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<>(); with ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<String>(); as Sahil used. And its working now! Thank you!!!

Comment: According to java 8 u can use ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<>() instead of ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<String>(). Both are fine. No issues.
If it worked plz vote up and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
cursordata.moveToFirst()
```

after

```
List<String> li_records=new ArrayList<String>;
Cursor cursordata = myDb.getAllData();
```

use do while loop like this,

```
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursordata.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
           String productname = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("product")));
           li_records.add(productname);
        } while (cursordata.moveToNext());
    }
String[] products=li_records.toArray();
```

use this array in your adapter

Comment: Thank you, that worked. It outputs now the first row from the database. Could you suggest a method, how I can output all of the rows?

Comment: If this the appropriate answer than please accept the answer

Comment: You got the all records or not? If not i can tell u?

Comment: try storing all the record in some array and than use them,
I have edited the answer hope it will help you out.

Comment: Still outputs only the last row

Comment: I had made changes in answer. If it still not working than please update you code in question so that i can see where is the problem.